# When ever i call this function, it does not tell me its a prime number when i know it is a prime number e.g. 5

Tags: javascript, function, primes

Prime number problem on JavaScript. Whenever I ask the user to enter an input and then run the code below, it returns false always even if I know the number is a prime.

```js
            let number = prompt("Enter a number to test as a prime number:");
            let divisor = 2; 

            function isPrime(number, divisor) {
                if (number == 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (number == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (number % divisor == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (number % divisor !== 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (divisor * divisor > number) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (divisor > number) {
                    return true; 
                }
                else {
                    divisor++;
                    return false;
                }
            }           
            alert(isPrime(number, divisor));
            console.log(number);
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime, but you are returning true.  2 is a prime number, but you are returning false.  I suspect you got your logic backwards for what's a prime and what's not a prime.

Comment: your formula is wrong

Comment: what is `isPrime < number` supposed to do?